# Can i update the part of file with new content in all files in Linux

Tags: linux, file, shell, sed, awk

I have 50 files which have this function

```
public function __construct()
    {   $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->isDeleted = false;
    }
```

Now is there any way that i can append these lines inside that function in all files using sed or awk or whatever way it is possible

Like suppose the file.php is

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->age = 20;

    }
```

I want that it should become like this

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->age = 20;
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->isDeleted = false;

    }
```

Comment: Yes you can. What did you try? Did you read some documentation on `sed` or `awk` ?

Comment: i read docs on sed but i am not able to think how check the multiple lines for matching. i can do simple string replacement but this was difficult for me

Comment: You probably don't need to *match* several lines, only to *insert* several lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! >append.txt
>         $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
>         $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
>         $this->isActive = true;
>         $this->isDeleted = false;
> !
cat <<\! >file
> public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->age = 20;
> 
>     }
> !
sed '/$this->age = 20/r append.txt' file
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->age = 20;
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->isDeleted = false;

    }
sed -i '/$this->age = 20/r append.txt' file{1..50} # file1 to file50
```

EDIT:

To ***insert*** before closing curly brace:

```
sed -i '$!s/$/\\/' append.txt
sed -i '/^public function __construct()/,/^\s*}/!b;/^\s*}/i\'"$(<append.txt)" file{1..50}
```

Comment: actually the age=20 is just an example. it may have diff line but thing is to append lines before the terminating "}" of the constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -i 's/\$this->age = 20\;/\$this->age = 20\;\n\t\$this->createdAt = new DateTime()\;\n\t\$this->updatedAt = new DateTime()\;\n\t\$this->isActive = true\;\n\t\$this->isDeleted = false\;/g' file.php
```